# Вывод аргументов псевдомассива arguments

Tags: javascript, return

```js
 function foo(ags){
   document.write(this.a+"<br>")
   document.write(ags)
 };

 obj={
   a:2
 };

 var bar = function(){
   return foo.apply(obj, arguments)
 };

 bar("Hello")
```

Вопрос по псеводмассиву `arguments`, в первом варианте всё работает, тоесть, я передают в `bar()` при вызове нужный аргумент, ну и он чудесным образом подставляется в функцию `foo()` при вызове! Вопрос в следующем!

```js
function foo(ags){
  document.write(ags)
};

var bar = function(){
  return foo(arguments)
};

bar("Hello")
```

Данный код (который второй) выводи `[object Arguments]`почему? Что изменилось то? (ну кроме того, что функция фу больше не вызвается с `.apply(obj)`) Причём, интересно то, что если вместо `return foo(arguments)` ввести  `return foo(arguments[0])` то всё работает, и в окно документа выводится `"Hello"`!Просьба объяснить на доступном языке!

---

И кстати, просто для более детального понимания, я же правильно рассуждаю, что В `return foo.apply(obj, arguments)` эта самая `arguments` является тем самым псеводмассивом `arguments`, в который записываются аргументы функции `bar()` при её вызове?

Comment: *Что изменилось то?* - изменилось то, *что функция `foo` больше не вызвается с `.apply(obj)`*

Comment: Оо, серьездно! Да вы что! Не может быть! А поконструктивнее можно? Это я и без вас (если конечно вы читали вопрос) заметил!

Comment: Я и скопировал это с вашего вопроса :-) Вы написали разный код - получили разный результат. А вот если вы напишите так `foo[arguments]`, то `foo` вообще не вызовется. И вы тоже будете спрашивать - Что изменилось то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае Вы вызываете `apply` и массив `arguments` "раскладывается" по аргументам функции `foo`

Во втором случае Вы передаете в функцию массив аргументов и он интерпретируется как массив.

Вот так во втором случае Вы бы получили ожидаемый результат:

```js
function foo(ags){
  document.write(ags)
};

var bar = function(){
  return foo(...arguments)
};

bar("Hello")
```

---

Или аналогичный второму вывод, но для первого примера: `call` передает массив `arguments` как первый  аргумент вызова функции `foo`

```js
function foo(ags){
  document.write(ags)
};

var bar = function(){
  return foo.call(0, arguments)
};

bar("Hello")
```

Comment: Stranger in the Q, так я и не понял, почему в первом случае массив arguments раскладывается , а во втором он просто передаётся массивом, такое ощущение что вы просто констатировали факт того, что просиходит, ну хотябы скажите где можно прочитать более детально об этих двух примерах? почему (obj,arguments) раскладывается, а (arguments) это просто массив . . .

Comment: @Muranx так работают функции `call`, `apply` и `bind`, прочитать про это можно здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply

Comment: @Muranx  `такое ощущение что вы просто констатировали факт того, что просиходит` - а Вы не этого хотели? я Вам даже привел пример где это работает наоборот? Или этого не достаточно для понимания? Или Вы хотели получить ответ на вопрос почему именно так  сделали создатели языка?

Comment: Stranger in the Q, не поймите меня не правильно, просто я хотел более детального объяснения! Ваш пример foo.call(0,arguments) в принципи понятен, единственное, я пока не сталкивался с записью ...arguments! Всё равно спасибо!

Comment: @Muranx не стесняйтесь спрашивать, с я с радостью отвечу =)

Comment: Stranger in the Q, удачи вам!